# Native ionic 2 geolocation is not working on android device

Tags: android, cordova, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am using the native Ionic 2 Geolocation plugin and it does not work as expected. First, I add the plugin.

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

I then import the plugin and issue a call to get the current position.

```
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Geoposition, GeolocationOptions } from 'ionic-native/dist/plugins/geolocation';

export class MyComponent {
 protected getLocation():Promise<Geoposition> {
  let options:GeolocationOptions = {
   maximumAge: 0, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: false
  };
  return Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
   .catch(error => { console.error(error.message) };
 }
}
```

I've also checked my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I noticed that the timeout is always exceeded. If I leave it to the default (timeout is set to infinity by default), then around 20 minutes later, I do actually get a geo position. Of course, 20 minutes is not ideal.

I also tried using the `navigator` as follows. But I get the exact same results.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
 position => {
  console.info('using navigator');
  console.info(position.coords.latitude);
  console.info(position.coords.longitude);
 },
 error => {
  console.warn('using navigator');
  console.warn(error.code);
  console.warn(error.message);
 },
 options
);
```

When testing on `Chrome`, the code works as expected; the only difference is that I get a popup asking if I want to allow the page to access my location.

I saw a lot of people have the same problem on SO with Ionic too, but that is with version 1. I wanted to ask this question in the context of Ionic 2.

By the way, I've also updated Cordova and the version is showing up as 6.0.2.

```
npm update -g cordova
```

Version information

- Ionic 2.0.0-beta.30
- Cordova 6.0.2
- Gulp CLI 1.2.1 and Local 3.9.1

Comment: Faced the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: no, i have not found a solution. the other day i looked at ionic 2, and there is a new geolocation plugin, I'm going to try that. i will post the link later and try to see if it helps any.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      };

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=> {
        console.info('using navigator');
        console.info(position.coords.latitude);
        console.info(position.coords.longitude);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      }, options);
    }
```

Remember to import `Geolocation`:

```
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
```

And add plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

Comment: This works beautifully. On the newer version with promises you would do geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => { //some logic here });

Comment: how can i let this function run if the location is off then turn it on .
i mean if the location is off geolocation will return error, so if later i turn it on while i'm onthe same page , the geolocation will not run again , so how can i let it run again like listener on location state.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I found a solution. The problem was with mine GPS module. Eventually it stopped find my location at any site. I reloaded my phone and now everything works.

So at first check if you can determine your location on site such maps.google.com. If it can't determine your location, then the problem is with your phone. Try to reload it or reflash it.

Answer (score 1):

Install both cordova dependencies

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Add this permissions to AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Please keep in mind, when running *ionic cordova run android -l* geolocation will throw this unsecure error.
Test it on ur browser or do a simple run with

```
ionic cordova run android
```

It solved the problem for me, hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused whey you have added only the ionic plugin and forgot to add the cordova plugin(not sure why it's not installed by ionic plugin add command):

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

and then:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

installing the cordova plugin can fix the error in some situations.

This also happens when running the application on browser with `ionic serve` as cordova plugins are not available.